# Suggested edit review queue not working properly?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, suggested-edits, reviewing

The last 2 times I've tried using the suggested edit review queue, it's been doing some weird things for me.  On a bad edit, I would fill out the reject pop-up, hit reject, and then nothing.  I'm not advanced to the next item in the queue, and the 4 buttons remain active at the top.

I'm fairly certain that my reviews are being acted upon, so hitting skip accomplishes the task, but I'm receiving negative feedback, which in this case is worse than no feedback at all.

Comment: Are you using a mobile browser, by any chance? If so, [you're not the only one experiencing problems](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161271/is-there-a-bug-that-causes-review-queue-actions-fail-often-using-mobile-safari)...

Comment: @Laura: Yes, I am.  That may be the cause.

Comment: And I just checked your site's [mobile access usage statistics from quantcast](https://www.quantcast.com/gaming.stackexchange.com#!mobileWeb) - your site has similar mobile share (26% globally - 34% USA) to Ask Different (27% globally - 31% USA). The other 5 top traffic sites, Stack Overflow, Ask Ubuntu and SuperUser have between 1% and 5% mobile usage so we appear to be the outliers in terms of mobile users.

Comment: @bmike: is that over the past month?  Realize that the data for Arqade (and Ask Different) would be highly skewed for December, since many of us are still coming here on mobile devices over Christmas, but not necessarily to the trinity.

Comment: Yes - the mobile report I linked to is a floating 30 day window. It will be interesting to see if things taper off or take off as more people start using their mobile devices in 2013. In terms of user base - Mobile is Apple's business now. I can't speak for how your audience will use mobile in the next year, but it will be fun to watch.

Comment: @MBraedley Sorry for the necro, I'm just cleaning up Meta a bit. I assume you haven't had similar issues since the rollout of the responsive design site a few years back? Want me to mark this resolved (completed or no-repro etc)?

Comment: @Robotnik Honestly, haven't really looked at the review queues in the past (X>>24) months (and only had a single item that I didn't feel qualified to review just now), so this can probably get resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro)

I was unable to reproduce this when testing the review queues.

Given the site overall (and the review queues in particular) have had a major responsive design overhaul since this bug was found, it's likely this was inadvertently addressed as part of those changes.